# Right align text in text field - vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin, textfield

What are my options if i want to right-align the text in vaadin text field ? is there any way to do this without using css ?

Css options will also be usefull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you can't align text to right in a TextField with vaadin. But you can do it with the CSS like this:

- first set the style name:

  `TextField text = new TextField();
   text.setStyleName("my-text");`
- add CSS :

  `.v-textfield-my-text{
     text-align:right !important;
   }`

Comment: Can you please elaborate on where the CSS code needs to be placed exactly?

Comment: I don't remember the place of the CSS file. But in your theme you must have a generated CSS file that you can edit.

Comment: I tried putting your code in each of the three SCSS files. It didn't result in any change. However I did some testing after that by setting the caption to red and bold and it showed up. So the problem seems to be in the text-align component itself. May I ask which version of Vaadin were you using when posting this? I'm using Vaadin 7. Maybe it has changed in time and doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I was using Vaadin 6.

Answer (score 8):

Since Vaadin 7.5:

```
TextField text = new TextField();
text.addStyleName(ValoTheme.TEXTFIELD_ALIGN_RIGHT);
```

Comment: Works in vaadin 8 as well

Comment: or use ValoTheme.TEXTFIELD_ALIGN_RIGHT instead which is the same string